# Orion Context Broker - references to data models

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm preparing laboratory script for presenting features of of OCB, however
there is a misconception on how OCB references to Data Models defined by
FIWARE. I'm aware of parameter 'type', which is supplied along with new
entity. The problem is connected to OCB. How does it difference between data models?

I can add variables from different data model which don't match. I
can't find the controller for it and if there is no any that's really shame. The problem I got is connected with situation:

1. Creating entity with declared type for instance: Device
2. Adding some parameter, which is not specified in Device schema. It could be dateLastWatering from Garden data model.

It doesn't make any sense, how the OCB reacts to that?

From my experience it just "swallows" the updated content as long as semantic of command is correct.

I received information that a restriction can be implemented in application layer, however in my opinion it should be supplied along with OCB already.

That way model can be mistaken and the example is not really educational. It
could be useful if after defining a model for entity, OCB could interact
somehow with user and check, or debug what it receives. That way it would be
more professional I guess and fore sure more safe to use. If OCB doesn't have
that feature is there a possibility for further development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orion Broker is totally agnostic with regards to Data Models. Orion is not intended to check schemas or perform data validation. In fact, it is a nice feature that the schema of the Data is free and up to applications.

However, FIWARE defines Data Models to promote harmonization in certain domains, for instance smart cities. So it is nice to reuse or extend existing data models for the sake of data portability.

Comment: Regarding the applications, are there any which could serve in presentation manner?  I mean some that are using OCB and are on the same open source license. I found one on fiware's website that was written as a part of hackathron or sth like that, however it not really helpfull.

Comment: Bumping the topic. Any app referencing OCB will be useful. Or is OCB really not used by anyone? I know NEC has its implemention of NGSI api but I guess companies connected to FIWARE should use OCB am I right?